# Custom Toast in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-toast

I want an custom Toast in Jetpack Compose but didn't found any helpful documentation regarding this any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom Toasts are deprecated in favor of SnackBar.
So they mostly won't have support in Jetpack Compose.

**References.**
[StackOverflow Post - Custom Toasts are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312296/method-setview-is-deprecated).
[Android code change deprecating Custom Toast with explaination](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/7b843abc1c7cd53096557909f31216b93c3ca674)

> Deprecating custom toasts as discussed, the reasons are:
>
> - We're blocking background custom toasts for security reasons (go/toast-abuse).
> - This means custom toasts are only possible if the app is in the foreground. In the foreground the app has control over its own view
>   hierarchy and is capable of creating any visual elements it would
>   otherwise use custom toasts for.
> - If we were to declare ongoing support for foreground toasts the developer would be in a situation where they either check for
>   foreground status of the app before posting a custom toast or they
>   accept that the information they want to display may not be shown at
>   all. This is not great.
> - There is also a desire to avoid custom toasts altogether since they hurt UX consistency
>   (https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1r5WEofZ_G3B9M65nS37uD4RqA4iV9HUmngyE6ZpBSsw/edit#slide=id.g7b69852da2_0_0).
>
> Also added a recommendation to use Snackbars while the app is in the
> foreground.

[Toast Abuse - Attack using Android Toast](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-toast-message-overlay-attack/)

Answer (score 1):

Until version `30`(R), `setView` method could be used. As stated here now either use the standard `Toast` or go to `Snackbar`

`Toast` -> `setView`

```
/**
 * Set the view to show.
 *
 * @see #getView
 * @deprecated Custom toast views are deprecated. Apps can create a standard text toast with the
 *      {@link #makeText(Context, CharSequence, int)} method, or use a
 *      <a href="{@docRoot}reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar">Snackbar</a>
 *      when in the foreground. Starting from Android {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#R}, apps
 *      targeting API level {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#R} or higher that are in the background
 *      will not have custom toast views displayed.
 */
@Deprecated
public void setView(View view) {
    mNextView = view;
}
```