# Customize Toast in Jetpack Compose. Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to customize Toast in Jetpack Compose? Need to change text color.
I can't find the documentation for this

Comment: Maybe a Snackbar is a better way.

Comment: Kindly refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69814172/9636037)