# How to show custom Toast using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-toast

I would like to show custom toast. How to achieve this?

This is my code, but this is deprecated and it crashes with logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView{3ed3fe7 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
```

```
        Toast
            .makeText(context, "TESTTESTTEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .apply {
                view = ComposeView(context).apply {
                    setContent {
                        CustomToastWithIcon(
                            message = stringResource(id = R.string.cart),
                            ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_info)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .show()
```

I tried defining it like this, but still crash.

```
        val composeView = ComposeView(context).apply {
            setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(this.findViewTreeLifecycleOwner())
            setContent {
                CustomToastWithIcon(
                    message = stringResource(id = R.string.cart),
                    ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_info)
                )
            }
```

Also read:
[Custom Toast in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813731/custom-toast-in-jetpack-compose/69814172#69814172)

Or is it possible to change background and icon from function

```
        Toast
            .makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

Edit:
Snackbar with scaffold was a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Toast in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813731/custom-toast-in-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score -5):

Snackbar is mostly recommended.
But if you want to use "Toast", you can define your own composable.

```
@Composable
fun Toast(message:String){
    makeText(LocalContext.current,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Make sure to import
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Toast.makeText

Comment: The downvotes are because toasts is a side effect, and calling them like so tie them with recompositions. They should be called in effect handlers such as LaunchedEffect.